# how to use 3rd party API( jar ) file with javax.script?

Tags: java, javax.script

Can we can use 3rd party jar file with javax.scripting framework.
Is there anything for adding to classpath?

Comment: please be more specific, what library do you want to add, is it an implementation of a scripting engine?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect simply to put it on the classpath of the process invoking the scripting framework, and then import the relevant classes (the import statement/mechanism will obviously differ depending upon what script language you're using)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Try this.

```
// import the packages.
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.net);
importPackage(java.util);
importPackage(java.util.jar);

// Create a loader function
function loadJar( filename ){
    var file = new File(filename);
    // Create the class loader
    var loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
    // The JAR file
    var jar = new JarFile(file);
    var entries = jar.entries();

    while (entries.hasMoreElements()){
        var element = entries.nextElement();
        if (element.getName().endsWith(".class")){
            try {
                // Load the class
                loader.loadClass(element.getName());
            } catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Execute this script with all the jars before any other and this would work. Else you can simply add the required libraries to the class-path by editing the `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Also I recommend you to use `beanshell` which works even on JDK 1.1

For beanshell, you can use

```
addClassPath("<jar-file-name>");
```